# I'm running Plots from preserves list of curves but color doesn't change

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am trying to plot few curves in different colors, but it doesn't work.  I keep on getting the same color for all, even though I verified the the Color section is changed.  I've even done it manually to be sure.

I have another class which creates the PointPairList List and another which changes the color.

```
myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
int index = 0;
foreach (PointPairList item in cMasterGraph)
{
    myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
    // GraphPane object holds one or more Curve objects (or plots)
    myPane.YAxis.Type = AxisType.Log;
    Color color = GetNextColor();
    // Add cruves to myPane object
    LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve(cGraphname[index], item, color, SymbolType.None);
    LineItem myCurve2 = myPane.AddCurve(cGraphname[index], item, Color.Yellow, SymbolType.None );
    //myCurve.Add(tempcurve);
    myCurve.Line.Width = 1.0F;
    index++;
    //myCurve.IsSelected = true;
    // I add all three functions just to be sure it refeshes the plot.  
    zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
    zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
    zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
}
```

I've been stuck on that problem already for too much time.

Comment: Please post the `GetNextColor()` source code as well.

Comment: private Color GetNextColor()
        {
            Color[] mColors = { Color.Firebrick, Color.ForestGreen, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Red, Color.Purple };
            if (mLastColor >= mColors.Length) mLastColor = 0;
            return mColors[mLastColor++];
        }

Comment: I had verified that the color change but its still doesn't work, also try to modify the Color by editing the value but I got the same results no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

```
LineItem myCurve = myPane.AddCurve(cGraphname[index], item, color, SymbolType.None);
LineItem myCurve2 = myPane.AddCurve(cGraphname[index], item, Color.Yellow, SymbolType.None );
```

i think :

myCurve and myCurve2 have same item, so when you have draw myCurve then you draw myCurve2, myCurve covered by myCurve2(Color.Yellow).